# Save/restore large global objects at Process Death in Android

Tags: android

I'm getting a `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel`. I want to store large objects in `onSaveInstanceState` bundle. Can I save data in shared preference in side the `onSaveInstanceState` and retrive the data in `onCreate` at process death?

I want some explanation about storing data via preference in `onSaveInstanceState` method of android. All answer says "The amount of data should be kept small", but I want to store large data.

Can I store large data/object in preference via Gson?

Answer (score -2):

Storing large data directly in SharedPreferences, especially within the **onSaveInstanceState** method, is not recommended. SharedPreferences are designed for storing small amounts of key-value pairs, typically for storing user preferences or application settings.

**onSaveInstanceState** is primarily used for saving the transient state of an Activity, not for persisting large amounts of data. The data stored in onSaveInstanceState is intended to be used for restoring the state of the Activity during configuration changes (e.g., screen rotations) or when the Activity is temporarily destroyed and recreated (e.g., due to a low memory situation).

**SharedPreferences** have limited storage capacity, and storing large data sets can lead to performance issues and increased memory usage. Additionally, saving large data sets in onSaveInstanceState can impact the performance of the UI thread and cause delays in the user interface updates.

If you have large data that needs to be persisted, it is recommended to use other storage options, such as a database (e.g., SQLite) or saving to disk (e.g., in a file). These storage options are better suited for handling larger data sets and provide more efficient and scalable solutions for data persistence.

In summary, it's best to avoid storing large data in SharedPreferences, especially within the onSaveInstanceState method. Instead, consider using appropriate storage mechanisms based on the size and complexity of your data.

Comment: Can I store large data/object via Gson?

Comment: Yes, you can use Gson (Google's JSON serialization/deserialization library) to store large data or objects in Android. Gson provides a convenient way to convert Java objects to JSON strings and vice versa.

Comment: I know that but I want to know about what is the recommended way for storing large data at process death and how to handle TransactionTooLargeException?

Comment: The **TransactionTooLargeException** is thrown when the data being passed exceeds the binder transaction limit (usually 1 MB). To handle this exception, check the size of the data you are storing in the **Bundle** to ensure it doesn't exceed the transaction limit. If it does, consider alternative storage methods for the large data. Also if it is possible, make small chunks of data to store, to avoid **TransactionTooLargeException**.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT